# WPF window properties only visible at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resources, wpf-style

I'm a XAML-beginner and also learning it by myself.
So in the App.xaml I have the following Styles:

```
<Application.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="Colors" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF404040"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF25CBDA"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF25CBDA"/>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="BaseWindowStyle" TargetType="Window" BasedOn="{StaticResource Colors}">
            <Setter Property="Title" Value="MainWindow"/>
            <Setter Property="WindowState" Value="Normal"/>
            <Setter Property="Icon" Value="Icon.ico"/>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="MainWindowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Window}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseWindowStyle}">
            <Setter Property="ResizeMode" Value="CanResize"/>
            <Setter Property="ShowInTaskbar" Value="True"/>
        </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

That's how I use the Style in the MainWindow.xaml:

```
Style="{DynamicResource MainWindowStyle}"
```

My problem is that the properties, like the background, are only visible at runtime. It's probably obvious but I really don't get it.

Comment: What do you mean by "Visible only at runtime"? Where do you want to get them visible? Do you mean on Designer?

Comment: Yes, in the designer the window is white, but at the runtime it's dark grey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome, DeJoon! It's unclear exactly what it is that you don't get.  What do you want to happen, or expect to happen?  Are you saying that you don't know what the background color looks like until you run the app, but you want to see it at design time? You should be able to see the color and the properties via the XAML Designer.

I took your code, commented out one line related to "icon.ico" because I don't have that file, and I was able to see your background color as a dark grey color from the designer.  See here:

[image]

Here is my MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
<Window x:Class="StyleTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StyleTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" Style="{DynamicResource MainWindowStyle}">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: For example the background in the designer is white but if I run the app then the background changes to the color I defined in the App.xaml. Well probably the issue is (I will test it later) that line because I don't see the dark grey in the designer.

Comment: No that wasn't the issue. Did you changed something in the .cs file? My background is still white. If I change the all the ```StaticResource``` in ```DynamicResource``` in the App.xaml then I can see the gray in the designer but then I can't start the app.

Comment: DeJoon, I edited my answer to show my MainWindow.xaml.cs (I was using `DynamicResource` by the way).  I changed it to `StaticResource` to see if it crashes, but I was still able to start the app.  Sorry I couldn't be of more help than this.